# SQL hierarchy count totals report

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, parent-child, hierarchy

I'm creating a report with SQL server 2012 and Report Builder which must show the total number of Risks at a high, medium and low level for each Parent Element.

Each Element contains a number of Risks which are rated at a certain level. I need the total for the Parent Elements. The total will include the number of all the Child Elements and also the number the Element itself may have.

I am using CTEs in my query- the code I have attached isn't working (there are no errors - it's just displaying the incorrect results) and I'm not sure that my logic is correct??

Hopefully someone can help. Thanks in advance.

*My table structure is:*

**ElementTable**

ElementTableId(PK) ElementName ElementParentId

**RiskTable**

RiskId(PK) RiskName RiskRating ElementId(FK)

*My query:*

```
WITH cte_Hierarchy(ElementId, ElementName, Generation, ParentElementId)
     AS (SELECT ElementId,
                NAME,
                0,
                ParentElementId
         FROM   Extract.Element AS FirtGeneration
         WHERE  ParentElementId IS NULL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT NextGeneration.ElementId,
                NextGeneration.NAME,
                Parent.Generation + 1,
                Parent.ElementId
         FROM   Extract.Element AS NextGeneration
                INNER JOIN cte_Hierarchy AS Parent
                        ON NextGeneration.ParentElementId = Parent.ElementId),
     CTE_HighRisk
     AS (SELECT r.ElementId,
                Count(r.RiskId) AS HighRisk
         FROM   Extract.Risk r
         WHERE  r.RiskRating = 'High'
         GROUP  BY r.ElementId),
     CTE_LowRisk
     AS (SELECT r.ElementId,
                Count(r.RiskId) AS LowRisk
         FROM   Extract.Risk r
         WHERE  r.RiskRating = 'Low'
         GROUP  BY r.ElementId),
     CTE_MedRisk
     AS (SELECT r.ElementId,
                Count(r.RiskId) AS MedRisk
         FROM   Extract.Risk r
         WHERE  r.RiskRating = 'Medium'
         GROUP  BY r.ElementId)
SELECT rd.ElementId,
       rd.ElementName,
       rd.ParentElementId,
       Generation,
       HighRisk,
       MedRisk,
       LowRisk
FROM   cte_Hierarchy rd
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_HighRisk h
                    ON rd.ElementId = h.ElementId
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_MedRisk m
                    ON rd.ElementId = m.ElementId
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_LowRisk l
                    ON rd.ElementId = l.ElementId
WHERE  Generation = 1
```

Edit:

*Sample Data*

```
ElementTableId(PK) -- ElementName -- ElementParentId
1 ------------------- Main --------------0
2 --------------------Element1-----------1
3 --------------------Element2 ----------1
4 --------------------SubElement1 -------2

RiskId(PK) RiskName RiskRating ElementId(FK)
a -------- Financial -- High -----  2
b -------- HR --------- High -----  3
c -------- Marketing -- Low ------- 2
d -------- Safety -----Medium ----- 4
```

Sample Output:

```
Element Name   High   Medium   Low  
Main ---------- 2 ---- 1 -------1
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say the code you have isn't working?  Do you get an error?

Comment: @TabAlleman the query is displaying incorrect results- there are no error messages

Comment: What result does it display and how is it different from what you want?

Comment: @taballeman it is not showing the total for each parent and its children. it is only showing the total for the parent itself - excluding all of the children results

Comment: add sample data and desired output

Comment: @nodisplayname sample data and desired output added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your sample tables

```
SELECT * INTO #TABLE1
FROM
(    
    SELECT 1 ElementTableId, 'Main' ElementName ,0 ElementParentId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'Element1',1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'Element2',1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'SubElement1',2
)TAB

SELECT * INTO #TABLE2
FROM
(    
    SELECT 'a' RiskId, 'Fincancial' RiskName,'High' RiskRating ,2 ElementId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b','HR','High',3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c', 'Marketing','Low',2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'd', 'Safety','Medium',4
)TAB
```

We are finding the children of a parent, its count of `High`,`Medium` and `Low` and use `cross join` to show parent with all the combinations of its children's `High`,`Medium` and `Low`

**UPDATE**

The below variable can be used to access the records dynamically.

```
DECLARE @ElementTableId INT;
--SET @ElementTableId = 1
```

And use the above variable inside the query

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
     SELECT *,0 [LEVEL]  FROM #TABLE1 WHERE ElementTableId = @ElementTableId
     UNION ALL
     SELECT E.*,e2.[LEVEL]+1  FROM #TABLE1 e 
     INNER JOIN CTE1 e2 on e.ElementParentId = e2.ElementTableId
     AND E.ElementTableId<>@ElementTableId
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT E1.*,E2.*,COUNT(RiskRating) OVER(PARTITION BY RiskRating) CNT 
    from CTE1 E1
    LEFT JOIN #TABLE2 E2 ON E1.ElementTableId=E2.ElementId  
)
,CTE3 AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT T1.ElementName,C2.RiskRating,C2.CNT  
    FROM #TABLE1  T1
    CROSS JOIN CTE2 C2
    WHERE T1.ElementTableId = @ElementTableId
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE3
PIVOT(MIN(CNT)
      FOR RiskRating IN ([High], [Medium],[Low])) AS PVTTable
```

- [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b4c9/1)

**RESULT**

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

I am updating as per your new requirement

Here is sample table in which I have added extra data to test

```
SELECT * INTO #ElementTable
FROM
(    
    SELECT 1 ElementTableId, 'Main' ElementName ,0 ElementParentId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'Element1',1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'Element2',1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'SubElement1',2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 'Main 2',0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 'Element21',5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 'SubElement21',6
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 'SubElement22',7
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9, 'SubElement23',7
)TAB

SELECT * INTO #RiskTable
FROM
(    
    SELECT 'a' RiskId, 'Fincancial' RiskName,'High' RiskRating ,2 ElementId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b','HR','High',3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c', 'Marketing','Low',2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'd', 'Safety','Medium',4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'e' , 'Fincancial' ,'High'  ,5 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'f','HR','High',6
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'g','HR','High',6
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'h', 'Marketing','Low',7
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'i', 'Safety','Medium',8
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'j', 'Safety','High',8
)TAB
```

I have written the logic in query

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
     -- Here you will find the level of every elements in the table
     SELECT *,0 [LEVEL] 
     FROM #ElementTable WHERE ElementParentId = 0
     UNION ALL
     SELECT ET.*,CTE1.[LEVEL]+1 
     FROM #ElementTable ET 
     INNER JOIN CTE1 on ET.ElementParentId = CTE1.ElementTableId  
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    -- Filters the level and find the major parant of each child
    -- ie, 100->150->200, here the main parent of 200 is 100 
    SELECT *,CTE1.ElementTableId MajorParentID,CTE1.ElementName MajorParentName  
    FROM CTE1 WHERE [LEVEL]=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CTE1.*,CTE2.MajorParentID,CTE2.MajorParentName  
    FROM CTE1  
    INNER JOIN CTE2 on CTE1.ElementParentId = CTE2.ElementTableId
)
,CTE3 AS
(
    -- Since each child have columns for main parent id and name, 
    -- you will get the count of each element corresponding to the level you have selected directly
    SELECT DISTINCT CTE2.MajorParentName,RT.RiskRating ,
    COUNT(RiskRating) OVER(PARTITION BY MajorParentID,RiskRating) CNT 
    FROM CTE2 
    JOIN #RiskTable RT ON CTE2.ElementTableId=RT.ElementId  
)
SELECT MajorParentName, ISNULL([High],0)[High], ISNULL([Medium],0)[Medium],ISNULL([Low],0)[Low]
FROM CTE3
PIVOT(MIN(CNT)
      FOR RiskRating IN ([High], [Medium],[Low])) AS PVTTable
```

- [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86003/1)

Comment: Hi @sarah avanavu
Thanks a million for your help. This looks great. But how would I get this same result without including the WHERE statement stating ReviewId=1.. the only kind of WHERE statement I would like to include is one that states what Generation / Level of the hierarchy these Elements are from

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you provide sample data with updated requirement? @chestternutt

Comment: And where is the ReviewId here? @chestternutt

Comment: I have modified the query. Feel free to ask for any change @chestternutt

Comment: Sorry Sarath, I mean the ElementTableId!! The report needs to be dynamic so I don't want to have to enter a ElementTableId as this is an internal value. I need to enter the level/ generation that I want to see the totals of

Comment: So you want to get output corresponding to each level? ie, if you pass 1 as level, you should get high,medium and low count for that level as well as its children? @chestternutt

Comment: Yes, exactly, if you pass 1 it will show all Elements on Level 1 in the Hierarchy and the total number of risks that they have in high, medium, low....
The Id numbers in my system are completely random and internal so they are not useful. I need this to be as dynamic as possible. So if I can pass a parameter with the level  I need - it would be perfect. Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: Did you get the expected result from the query I have updated? @chestternutt

Comment: Yes, I did! Thank you. But it is a bit slow to run. Do you have any advice at how I could make it run a bit faster?

Comment: Recursive CTE is the most common pattern used to find the parent child relationship. It would be better to use RiskId as Identity field with clustered index and seperate a,b,c,d to other column like RiskName @chestternutt